# How can i format the date into specified format which comes from db in <g:select>

Tags: grails, groovy

I need to have a dropdown which holds dates.

when i write

```
<g:select id="dob" name="dob" from="${Person.list().dateOfBirth}"  value="${personInstance?.dateOfBirth}" />
```

this displays the date in the format `2011-05-17 00:00:00.0` But i need to have the format `mm/dd/yyyy`.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

This is the shortest solution I can think of (untested):

```
<g:set var="dateFormat" value="MM/dd/yyyy"/>

<g:select id="dob" name="dob" from="${Person.list().dateOfBirth*.format(dateFormat)}"  
    value="${personInstance?.dateOfBirth?.format(dateFormat)}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Grails has a [formatDate](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formatDate.html) Tag which you can use as a method call in this situation. Example:

`value="${formatDate(format:'mm/dd/yyyy', date: yourDate)}" />`

Comment: date:yourDate mean single date or list of Dates,Ill get only the list of dates in the format 2011-05-17 00:00:00.0

Answer (score 1):

```
optionValue="${{formatDate(format: 'mm/dd/yyyy', date: it.dateOfBirth)}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
<g:set var="sdf" value="${new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy')}"/>
<g:select from="${Person.list()}" name="dob" optionValue="${{sdf.format(it.dateOfBirth)}}" optionKey="${{sdf.format(it.dateOfBirth)}}"/>
```

Comment: here dateOfBirth is of type Date.

Comment: when i execute this i am getting exception that cannot invoke dateOfBirth on null object