# How can i get non repeated date values grails with <g:select >tag

Tags: grails, groovy

I have an option for selecting a date from a drop-down with `<g:select>`.  How can I get non-repeated date values through this?  This is the code to get date in the specified format from the domain class.

dob is of type Date.

```
<g:set var="dateFormat" value="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
<g:select id="dob" name="dob" from="${Person.list().dob*.format(dateFormat)}"    
    value="${personInstance?.dob?.format(dateFormat)}" />
```

Comment: I can't see any line of code...

Comment: you've asked this question already, if you're not happy with the answers you've received explain why, or improve the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029999/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-which-are-not-repeated-in-grails-with-gselect-tag

Comment: i am getting an exception with that.and i have the other property dob as i mention above,Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: If you put some effort into writing a good question, I'll put some effort into answering it. Showing what you've tried already, and the results it produces would be a good start

Comment: The code you've added doesn't show any evidence of an attempt to solve this problem yourself as it has simply been copy-pasted from an answer I gave to one of your other questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029080/how-can-i-format-the-date-into-specified-format-which-comes-from-db-in-gselect/6030238#6030238

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6043166/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 6):

Call `unique()` on the list of items?

ie:

```
def colonies = [ 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c' ]
println colonies.unique()
```

prints

```
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

Be aware however that `unique()` mutates the original collection, so

```
println colonies
```

after calling `unique()` also prints

```
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out evil collection mutation. For a collection containing immutable objects (like that above) you can workaround this by calling `colonies.clone().unique()`

Comment: I submitted a patch to groovy to allow passing of a boolean parameter to stop `unique` mutating the collection...  Fingers crossed it makes it into 1.8.1

Comment: this can be handled at controller side.But i need to get the list values from domain class  when i write <g:select> for example <g:select id="colony" name="colony" from="${Colony.list()}"  value="${colonyInstance?.name}" /> here fro the Colony i should display non repeated values.

Comment: @tim_yates nice one, if you post the JIRA link I'll vote for it

Comment: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4742 If you read the comments, it a more insidious issue than just my patch however :-(

Answer (score 3):

If "Colony" is a grails domain class, then you can alter your query to retrieve distinct values. You didn't provide details, but let's say your domain class is called "Colony" and it has a property called "name", which for some reason you haven't made a unique constraint. Then you can do the following:

```
//add this method to Colony.groovy
public static List listUnique() {
    Colony.withCriteria {
        projections {
            distinct "name"
        }
    }.sort() 
}

//in xxx.gsp
<g:select name="colony" from="${Colony.listUnique()}" />
```

I agree with tim_yates's answer above, but thought you might appreciate a grails/hibernate approach, as well.

Comment: BTW, this can be achieved with namedQueries too. See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html

Comment: Thanks ruslan that's a much nicer solution!

Comment: I implemented this in my code but am facing some hibernate exceptions

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Person.listUnique() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: listUnique()

Comment: @Odaiah did you make the method static?

Answer (score 0):

```
<g:set var="dateFormat" value="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
<g:select id="dob" name="dob" from="${Person.list().dob*.format(dateFormat).unique()}"    
    value="${personInstance?.dob?.format(dateFormat)}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Don .its working and i just applied unique() for another Domain class. it has not worked so i asked this question. and sorry